# webpack - How to bundle binaries with executable file permissions

Tags: webpack, electron, executable, electron-forge

I'm on Linux and I need to bundle ffmpeg in my electron + webpack project. Currently, the ffmpeg executable gets bundled like this:

```
.webpack
├── main
│   ├── assets
│   │   ...
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── index.js.map
│   └── native_modules
│       ├── ffmpeg
│       ├── ffprobe
│       ├── linux-x64
│       │   ├── ffmpeg
│       │   └── package.json
│       ├── package.json
│       └── presets
│           ...
└── renderer
    ...
```

The executables are bundled with the app, however, they are not in executable mode.

So far, I used a workaround, where I would change the file modes of the binaries in my app on launch, but that doesn't work when deploying as an AppImage.

So my question is, how can I tell webpack to bundle these files as executable binaries?

Comment: Did you manage to get an solution to this?

Comment: Take a look at the answer posted below. It's how I got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working using the `webpack-shell-plugin-next`. In `webpack.main.config.js`:

```js
const WebpackShellPluginNext = require('webpack-shell-plugin-next');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    new WebpackShellPluginNext({
      onBuildEnd: {
        scripts: [
          'chmod +x .webpack/main/native_modules/ffmpeg',
          'chmod +x .webpack/main/native_modules/ffprobe',
        ],
        blocking: false,
        parallel: true
      }
  ],
  // ...
}
```